# Taking the derivative of a 3-form

Tags: algebraic-topology, closed-form, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

Let $\omega = z^2 dx \land dy \land dw + yw^3 dy \land dz \land dw + z w dx \land dy \land dz$

We then have $d \omega = 2zdx \land dy \land dw + (w^3 dy + 3yw^2 dw) dy \land dz \land dw + (wdz + z dw) dx \land dy \land dz$.

I'm not sure I know how to expand the brackets, how can I proceed from here? And if the derivative is zero, how can I check if the form is exact?

Comment: The wedge product distributes over addition. Take care with the order of factors, naturally, since wedging is skew-symmetric. For exactness, your form is defined on the contractible set $\mathbf{R}^{4}$ (it has polynomial coefficients), so the Poincare lemma (closed implies exact) holds.

Comment: You're missing $dz$ in the first term and wedges in all terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic rules of exterior derivative are those:
$$
d(df) = 0,\\
d(f\wedge g) = df\wedge g + (-1)^p f\wedge dg,
$$
where $f$ is $p$-form.

For local coordinates it means that:
$$
df=d(h(x,y)du\wedge dv) = h'_x(x,y)dx\wedge du\wedge dv + h'_y(x,y)dy\wedge du\wedge dv.
$$

In your example, you differentiate $z^2$, but lose $dz$ part.

The expansion of brackets is very easy actually, since exterior product is distributive:
$$
(\alpha+\beta)\wedge \omega = \alpha\wedge\omega + \beta\wedge\omega.
$$

Finally, from general understanding, you differentiate 3-form of 4 coordinates, so you should get a 4-form. There is only one 4-form in 4 coordinates up to the coefficient: $$h(x,y,z,w)dx\wedge dy\wedge dz \wedge dw.$$ So you should what kind of answer you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now! So the second bracket becomes 0 and the last one becomes $z$ and we're left with $z dx \land dy \land dz \land dw$. Do you know how one would integrate this over $S^3$? I know that a three form you can turn into spherical coordinates and integrate over $S^2$, is it the same process here?